# how to add multiple button in stack view programmatically using array

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have used  [DLRadioButton](https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton) library. I need to add multiple buttons in vertical stack view using an array of string and load into stack view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    for item in 0...3{
        AccountStackView(at: item).setTitle("\(account[item])", for: .normal)
    }
}
func AccountStackView(at index:Int) -> DLRadioButton {
    return StackView.arrangedSubviews[index] as! DLRadioButton
}
```

Comment: this is the library i used ----https://github.com/DavydLiu/DLRadioButton

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: func AccountStackView(at index:Int) -> DLRadioButton {
        return StackView.arrangedSubviews[index] as! DLRadioButton
    } .

Comment: and in viewDidLoad ..->>for item in 0...3{
         AccountStackView(at: item).setTitle("\(account[item])", for: .normal)

        }

Comment: Add the information to the question instead of commenting so that people can read it easily.

Comment: what is an account array?

Comment: I added block of handling constranits of stackview. Did it help you?

Answer (score 1):

Add in your UIViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let array = [dLRadioButton0, dLRadioButton1, dLRadioButton2, dLRadioButton3] // change it if you already have an array of DLRadioButton buttons

    for item in array {
        item.setTitle("Your Text", for: .normal)
    }

    let yourStackView = addToStackViewButtons(array: array, andAddTo: self.view)
    for item in yourStackView.arrangedSubviews as! [DLRadioButton] {
        // do something with your DLRadioButton's
        item.backgroundColor = .green
    }
}

func addToStackViewButtons(array : [DLRadioButton], andAddTo yourView : UIView) -> UIStackView {
    let sv = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: array) // or just get link from storyboard via outlet link
    sv.distribution = .fillEqually
    sv.axis = .vertical

    sv.frame = yourView.frame
    yourView.addSubview(sv) // if you create stackview sv programmically

    // set frame of add your constraints if you need
    // for example:
    sv.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourView.leftAnchor)
    sv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourView.topAnchor)
    sv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourView.bottomAnchor)
    sv.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: yourView.rightAnchor)
    return sv
}
```